# regular expression with new line

Tags: php, regex

I want the string **FC Barcelona v BM Huesc , FC Ferrari v BM ameriF and C semari v AM buhari** from below code.

```
$mat = '<font color="white">FC Barcelona v BM Huesca

<font color="white">FC Ferrari v BM ameri

<font color="white">FC semari v AM buhari
';
```

I tried below code , but it does not seems to work.Any help will be appreciated.Thanks

```
preg_match_all('/<font color="white">(.*?)/',$mat,$mats);
var_dump($mats);
```

Edit: My real time example is below

```
<?php
$game = file_get_contents("http://www.firstrow1.eu/bet365/index.html");
preg_match_all('/<\/td><td><font color="white">(.*)/m',$game,$mats);
var_dump($mats);
?>
```

Comment: Change `.*?` to `.*`.

Comment: What do you mean by "did not work"?  What didn't work?  What did it do?

Comment: var_dump($mats); does not print anything

Comment: What did you get on `var_dump`? You should at least get the string `'<font color="white">'`. I think you need the `s` modifier. http://www.php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: In your url (`firstrow1.eu`), the string is `<font color='white'>` not `<font color="white">`.  This is one reason why you shouldn't use [regexes to read HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all("#<font color=\"white\">(.*?)\n#si", $mat, $mats);
```

It works!

Comment: There's no real benefit to enabling single-line mode since your non-greedy dot-star followed by a newline will stop at the first newline in the target string anyway.

Answer (score 2):

`.*?` will match nothing because it is relucant and matches as little as possible.  Since there is no other part of the expression after it, it is done when it has matched nothing.  Use `.*` because with all its greediness it will only match up to the end of the line.  Note that this is true regardless of whether you use the `m` modifier or not.